# Long running API polling in React application stops after some time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I work on a React application used by on-call technicians. It displays hardware alarms and allows users to triage those alarms.

The app polls an API for the alarms at 1 minute intervals. It also sends desktop notifications if the user has the window hidden.

We've got several user reports where the user notices it's been a large gap of time since the last alarm, they'll manually refresh the page, and it turns out there were alarms and the app didn't poll them in.

We do the polling in a useEffect, like this:

```js
    // Do initial data loading and set up polling
    useEffect(() => {
        refetch();

        let intervalId: number;

        if (pollingInterval) {
            intervalId = window.setInterval(() => refetch(), pollingInterval);
        }

        return () => window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [refetch, pollingInterval]);
```

This seems to work as advertised in development, and it's also been in use for several months, so it works *most* of the time, but seems to stop working randomly for some users.

My hypothesis is that the browser may be killing the javascript process after some time of inactivity. I am wondering if this approach is not robust enough for our use case. Would a web worker be a more appropriate place to do the API polling / desktop notifications?